# Can't access specific route on deployed heroku app (404 not found)

Tags: web-services, heroku, deployment, http-status-code-404, paas

So I have a web app with a specific route: `http://localhost:28389/WebServiceTestingAuthentification/webresources/teachers/` this returns a test json object which is seen below:
[image]

I deployed the app on heroku but when I try to access the same route I get a `404 Not found` error:
[image: s]

This is my teacher service:

```
@Path("teachers")
public class TeacherService {

public TeacherService() {
}

@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response getTeachers() throws Exception {
    return getResponse(new response.AuthorizationResponse(BaseResponse.SUCCESS, "Hello my private teachers", "jlk"));

}

protected Response getResponse(Object o) {
    return Response.ok(o)
            .build();
}
}
```

Comment: Do other routes work?

Comment: @Chris no they dont